# How to bind field to a column with different name with Elixir Ecto

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm trying to build a small app that's going to connect to legacy db. Is there a way to define Ecto model with attribute names different that table columns?

Something like:

```
schema "oauth_access_tokens" do
  field :token
  field :user_id, :integer, column: :resource_owner_id
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible right now.

A possible solution is to use views on the database level, but I'm not sure if it's a good idea.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping I missed something in the docs, but seems like not :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `source` option for [field](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#field/3).

```
:source - Defines the name that is to be used in the database for this field.
```

Example:

```
defmodule MyApp.Pet do
  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "pets" do
    field :first_name, :string, source: :name
    field :last_name, :string
  end
end
```